# Got error flowLayout

Tags: user-interface

probably i have a problem with my flowLayout it will gonna be error . how can i fix that please help me .

it seems the error  cannot resolve symbol class FlowLayout .

```
    import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class qwe extends JFrame
{
    private JButton but;
    private JLabel lab;
    private JTextField tex;

    public qwe()
    {
        lab = new JLabel("I am a label");
        add(lab);

        tex = new JTextField(15);
        add(tex);

        but = new JButton("Click me!");
        add(but);
    }

    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        qwe gui = new qwe();
        gui.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(200,125);
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: most probably FlowLayout class is not set in your classpath.

Comment: @SasiKathimanda what should i need to do ?

Comment: are you really want to extending a JFrame ?? why not create new JFrame instead.

Answer (score 1):

you need to import FlowLayout class 
    `import java.awt.FlowLayout;`
And also I have an advise for you :
 watch yout programming logic carefully. you have to set the layout of your qwe frame and then add other components to it.